# Doing a Soap requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am calling a soap web service. When we do a rest call we send key value pairs. Like that, I want to know that if we are doing a soap request what features are essential? eg:url

Comment: You don't want us to repeat the SOAP specification here. What is your question? Have you looked into generating a WCF client?

Comment: I want to do a soap call and get the xml response. For that, about what things should I focus on?  eg: authentication type, service url

Comment: do you have wsdl for that web service ? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Nop. I just use the url to add the web reference. I want to know whether there are any other things that I want to refer.